# Group array by number of characters

Tags: php, arrays

The following code puts the string into an array and sorts by number of characters in each element.

```
$str = 'audi toyota bmw ford mercedes dodge ...';

$exp = explode(" ", $str);

usort($exp, function($a, $b){
  if (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

How do I take this one dimensional array and group the elements by number of characters with the index indicating the number of chars. in the element group?

```
array(
[3] => array(bmw, ... )
[4] => array(ford, audi, ... )
[5] => array(dodge, ... )
)
```

**Is there a way to take the multidimensional array and print it in a php format?**

ie:

```
$arr = array(
"3" => array("bmw"),
"4" => array("audi"),
"5" => array("dodge")
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd probably be easiest to do this:

```
$exp = explode(" ",$str);
$group = []; // or array() in older versions of PHP
foreach($exp as $e) $group[strlen($e)][] = $e;
ksort($exp); // sort by key, ie. length of words
var_export($exp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'audi toyota bmw ford mercedes dodge';
$words = explode(" ", $str); // Split string into array by spaces
$ordered = array();
foreach($words as $word) { // Loop through array of words
    $length = strlen($word); // Use the character count as an array key
    if ($ordered[$length]) { // If key exists add word to it
        array_push($ordered[$length], $word);
    } else { // If key doesn't exist create a new array and add word to it
        $ordered[$length] = array($word);
    }
}
ksort($ordered); // Sort the array keys
print_r($ordered);
```